# emacs: in terminal selected string gets lost on ctrl-k

Tags: emacs, clipboard

1. I select an absolute file name with the mouse in a terminal
2. I want to open this file in a running emacs: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
3. Emacs mini buffer: contains "~/...."
4. I enter ctrl-a ctrl-k to delete "~/...."
5. I want to paste with middle button
6. "~/...." gets inserted, not the file name of step one.

How can I stop emacs from overwriting my text I selected with the mouse?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, probably the easiest solution is to yank (paste) the copied filename at the start of the mini buffer *before* performing the kill-to-end-of-line i.e. instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. You could replace the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> by a middle-click paste at the same point if you prefer to use the mouse.

Alternatively, according to this stackoverflow answer [delete (NOT kill) a line in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8422514) it should be possible to automatically add the externally-copied text to the emacs kill-ring by adding

```
(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)
```

to your emacs configuration - this should make the filename available for yanking by scrolling back through the kill ring using <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This have bothered me in the past as well.

The solution I found was to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> a delete only command. This worked for me, as I never used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to copy and paste.

Originally posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136581/72170)

```
;; Ctrl-K with no kill
(defun delete-line-no-kill ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-region
   (point)
   (save-excursion (move-end-of-line 1) (point)))
  (delete-char 1)
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'delete-line-no-kill)
```

Answer (score 0):

EMACS will convert multiple slashes to a root path, e.g. `//` becomes `/`
If you were to

1. leave whatever text is in the minibuffer
2. append a `/`
3. paste the absolute path in the minibuffer, appending it to existing text

The minibuffer will have a path such as `~//path2file/file`
EMACS will open `/path2file/file`

There's no need to reassign <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>, just learn how EMACS handles filenames in the minibuffer.
Read the GNU EMACS manual topic "Minibuffers for File Names" [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs-20.7/html_chapter/emacs_9.html); begin reading at the text "But you don't need to kill the default;"